# How to compare length of data in mysql type text using php?

Tags: php, mysql

i have this table name = `text_tab`

```
 _________________________
|  id  |     message     |
|  1   |     aaa         |
|  2   |     bb          |
|  3   |     ffff        |
|  4   |     ooooooo     |
|  5   |     gg          |
```

I want to check row that data in column `message` have max char.
And column `message` is type `text`.

in my answer will show `id=4`

I use order by message desc but not work, How can i do that ?

Comment: Also check out a few aggregate functions http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx one being `max()`

Comment: @robert dewere  `SELECT * FROM test_tab ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(message);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `CHAR_LENGTH` or `LENGTH` function yet? It would work like

```
SELECT id FROM text_tab ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(message) DESC
```

Instead of ordering by the `message` column directly, order by the `CHAR_LENGTH` of said column.